# Json Stream in Wcf c# service to array

Tags: c#, json, wcf, deserialization

I'm really bad with C# and would like your help doing the following; I am currently passing a Json Array to my WCF webservice. I need to take the json array and insert it into a list. I have no idea to deserialize in C#. Please suggest to me what is the best way of achieving this. My code looks as follows:

```
  public String UpdateOrderAddress(Stream userInfo)
  {
        try
        {               
           StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(userInfo);
           string JSONdata = reader.ReadToEnd();
           if (JSONdata == null)
           {                    
                return "null";
           }                        

           return JSONdata;     // Success !
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.ToString();
        }
  }
```

This is the data in the string that I get from the reader

```
[{"date":"2013-02-22 15:30:374:021","id":"1","description":"test","name":"test"},
"date":"2013-02-25 11:56:926:020","id":"2","description":"ghy","name":"fhh"},
"date":"2013-02-25 11:56:248:026","id":"3","description":"ghfm","name":"run"}]
```

Comment: have you tried JSON.net?

Comment: here is a sample : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/json-deserialize-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted doesn't show how are you trying to deserialize your json string so I don't really follow what's the relevance here but in any case, this is how to deserialize JSON into a concrete C# class.

1. Create a class that matches the structure of your Javascript objects as so:

   ```
   public class Data
   {
     public string  Date {get;set;}
     public int ID {get;set;}
     public string Description {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}
   }
   ```
2. Deserialize it using the [JavascriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) as so:

   ```
   var deserializedData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Data>>(jsonString);
   ```

Note that your original JSON string is incorrectly formatted. It's missing the opening `{` on each element of the array. It should really be:

> [{"date":"2013-02-22
>   15:30:374:021","id":"1","description":"test","name":"test"},
>   {"date":"2013-02-25
>   11:56:926:020","id":"2","description":"ghy","name":"fhh"},
>   {"date":"2013-02-25
>   11:56:248:026","id":"3","description":"ghfm","name":"run"}]

Now, if you attempt to deserialize the above, as so:

```
string json = @"[{""date"":""2013-02-22 15:30:374:021"",""id"":""1"",""description"":""test"",""name"":""test""},
   {""date"":""2013-02-25 11:56:926:020"",""id"":""2"",""description"":""ghy"",""name"":""fhh""},
   {""date"":""2013-02-25 11:56:248:026"",""id"":""3"",""description"":""ghfm"",""name"":""run""}]";

var deserializedData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Data>>(json);
```

You'll get a nice `List<Data>` back.

Also note that I didn't use a DateTime field for the corresponding `date` field in your Javascript object, the reason being that your sample dates are not valid DateTimes or at least a `DateTime` object cannot be created from that string representation. For instance, "15:30:374:021" makes no sense - I would imagine that 374 is the seconds field...

You need to add a reference to System.Web.Extensions to be able to use the JavascriptSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a representative class with your required properties to hold the values and use the [`JavascriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class. Call the [`Deserialize<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355316.aspx) method specifying your type to deserialize the JSON into your code.

Links in class names for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Newtonsoft.Json* Library. All you will need to do is:

```
List<YourClass> yourClassList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<YourClass>>(JSONdata);
```

You find more information, even samples [here](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.aspx)